# Exception not caught if raised after spawning std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, stdthread

I'm puzzled by the strange behavior of exceptions, which are thrown in main thread after spawning another thread:

```
void thread_body(){
    while(true) cout << "in thread" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try{
        auto t = std::thread( thread_body );

        throw std::runtime_error("error!");

        t.join();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

> ```
> in thread
> in thread
> in thread
> terminate called without an active exception
> The program has unexpectedly finished.
> ```

If I throw before spawning the thread like this:

```
throw std::runtime_error("error!");
auto t = std::thread( thread_body );
```

than it is caught normally:

> error!

Why exception is not caught in first case? What should I do to catch it in usual way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When exception is thrown thread object will be destroyed. But thread destructor will be called while it is still joinable. This causes `terminate` to be called so exception handler is never invoked.

Also writing into standard streams from different threads without proper synchronization is not a good idea.

Comment: "Also writing into standard streams from different threads without proper synchronization is not a good idea." - it's not a good idea, but the Standard does allow multiple threads to write to cout et al without explicit synchronisation.

Comment: Standard only requires that no race condition occurs. However produced output may be messed up.

Comment: Ok, but this means that any exceptions thrown in main thread after spawning any other threads are not possible to catch by outer catch block! This is weird and makes little sense because I'll need to insert separate try blocks after any thread creation. There should be some solution I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some research I found solution of this problem. One have to wrap the thread into the class and create its instance instead of creating the raw thread. In destructor one can check if thread is still joinable and perform actions to stop the thread body gracefully if possible. In such case when exception is thrown the destructor will be called while thread is still running and it will sort out the things.